# How to monitor mysql percentage disk utilization?

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql world and not sure if there is a way to calculate mysql TableSpace/DiskSpace utilization in percentage. I am aware mysql does not provide upper limit or free space like Oracle DB, but just space consumed by Index tables and Data Tables. I have decided to add these two values and divide with total space available for mountpoint mentioned in "datadir" attribute of mysql. My queries are :

1. Is this right way of doing this ??
2. What if databases/tables are created on different mountpoints. Is there a way to monitor available space for mysql instance then ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474591/how-can-you-determine-how-much-disk-space-a-particular-mysql-table-is-taking-up .                   Also for getting info on Disk utilization, O.S Monitoring, you can go with [MySQL Enterprise Monitor](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/monitor-features.html) or [MONyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog). MONyog fairly gives better visual representation than MySQL Enterprise Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

This query will return Tablename and number of records it has.

```
SELECT 
TABLE_SCHEMA AS `Database`,
TABLE_NAME AS `Table`,
TABLE_ROWS AS `Rows` 
FROM
information_schema.TABLES ;
```

This query will return databases on server w.r.t. Size */

```
SELECT 
TABLE_SCHEMA  AS `Database`,
SUM((data_length + index_length) / (1024 * 1024)) AS `Database_Size`
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
GROUP BY table_schema 
ORDER BY `Database_Size` DESC 
LIMIT 5 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this query:

```
select
  TABLE_SCHEMA,
  TABLE_NAME,
  (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024 AS SIZE
from information_schema.TABLES
```

but you notice this SIZE is less than sum of *.ibd and *.frm file on disk. This is because when you delete row from table data doesn't deleted from file. To clean *.ibd file you must run query:

```
optimize table table_name
```

The best solution for this is check file size for every table and compare with disk size.

Comment: Thanks Celudor. I have used below code snippet:


dbSizeArr= <<query to sum index and data length>>
dbSizeArr=($(echo "$dbSize" |awk '{ print $2}'))
 dbName=($(echo "$dbSize" |awk '{ print $1}'))
 cnt=${#dbName[@]}
 for (( i=0 ; i<${cnt} ; i++ ))
 do
  fieldA=${dbName[i]};
  sizeA=${dbSizeArr[i]};
  pct_size=$(echo "scale=5; $sizeA * 100 / $mount_datadir_usage" | bc -l )
  echo $fieldA $pct_size
 done

Comment: Not sure how to calculate if databases are on different mountpoints.